# Can't add OracleDriver to Subclipse build path

Tags: jdbc, eclipse-plugin, database-connection, ojdbc

I need to make some modifications to the Subclipse Eclipse svn plugin. To do so, I need to connect to a specific Oracle database, but my code keeps dying on this line:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

With (surprise) :

```
ClassNotFoundException
```

I've added the ojdbc.jar to the build path of my project
(org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core, the project that tries to connect to the database)

This works fine in a regular project, just not with the Subclipse plugin, so it's not being deployed I guess.

I do have it checked in this menu:

```
Configure Build Path -> Order and Export
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy the jar to the plugin directory.
2. Open the file "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" in the plugin project directory, switch to
   the "runtime" tab, and then click "add" button the the "class-path"
   section to select the driver jar file.